# Apache Camel CXF WebService with frontend web application

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf

I have made standalone `WebService` working with `apache camel cxf`. It listen on `9003` and `9004` port and then using routes like this:

```
   <route>
     <from uri="cxf:bean:queueManagerEndpoint" />
     <to uri="direct:callAddToqueueMethod" />
   </route>
```

It's handling the `WebService` calls.

application is run as:

```
    org.apache.camel.spring.Main main = new org.apache.camel.spring.Main();
    instance = main;
    main.enableHangupSupport();
    System.out.println("Starting camel...");
    main.run(args);
```

I would like to add some statistic page where I will be able to show how many calls is made and how do they look.
In the [camel docummentation](http://camel.apache.org/servlet.html) the only way to obtain this is as:

`web.xml`:

```
<web-app>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>Camel Http Transport Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and the `RouteBuilder`

```
from("servlet:hello?matchOnUriPrefix=true").process(new Processor() {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String contentType = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, String.class);
        String path = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, String.class);
        path = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/"));

        assertEquals("Get a wrong content type", CONTENT_TYPE, contentType);
        // assert camel http header
        String charsetEncoding = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_CHARACTER_ENCODING, String.class);
        assertEquals("Get a wrong charset name from the message heaer", "UTF-8", charsetEncoding);
        // assert exchange charset
        assertEquals("Get a wrong charset naem from the exchange property", "UTF-8", exchange.getProperty(Exchange.CHARSET_NAME));
        exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType + "; charset=UTF-8");
        exchange.getOut().setHeader("PATH", path);
        exchange.getOut().setBody("<b>Hello World</b>");
    }
});
```

And I believe it would do the job, however I would not want to build `html` page with `StringBuilder` is it possible to pass `jsp` page with `data template` to the `exchange.getOut().setBody()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use freemarker, a java based template engine to generate text output based on templates and changing data.
This template file is similar to jsp where you can define the format of your text and can use bean properties as place holders for dynamic data in that template.

Below components are involved

1. Text format - How the data should look like [ Template ]
2. Data - what is the data to be generated in the required format [ Data Model ]
3. Output Generator - Read the template, pass the data model and get the text output [ Freemarker library ]

[A sample working example to work with freemarker](http://www.kswaughs.com/2015/11/freemarker-java-template-engine.html)